# How to turn off shuffle in Apple Music on iPhone iOS 10.1.1?

Tags: iphone, music

When I play any album in Apple Music on my iPhone 6 Plus, iOS 10.1.1, the tracks are shuffled. i.e. when I press the >> button some track other than the next one is played.

The only icon related to shuffling that I can see anywhere in the app is 'Shuffle all'.

When I play an album I want to hear the tracks in the original order. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is somewhat hidden, but here's how to find the controls.

Start by tapping the bar at the bottom where you see the album art, currently playing song and play/pause and next song controls.

[image]

You get a sheet overlay which seems to end at the bottom of the screen, but if you scroll this down (drag up on the screen) you find the controls for shuffle and repeat.

[image]
[image]

Screenshots are from an iPhone 7, but I'd expect the controls to be positioned similarly on the Plus.

EDIT: In the updated iOS 10.2, the look of the controls have changed somewhat, and a hint showed up the first time I started playing music that the controls were available if I scrolled down.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The control on the iPhone 6 was indeed in the same place. I had no idea that screen could be swiped up.

Comment: @Lobert No, it doesn't look like there's anything else there to swipe up to. Took me a while to find it too.

Comment: What a bad UX! I spent 5 minutes trying to find out how to turn off shuffle and still couldn't find it.

Comment: This app is so unintuative.  I hate that it always "assumes" I want to shuffle.  I've performed the steps above and my Shuffle is not on.  When I select a song to play from it does go in order as I want... but if I stop the music and later try to resume it again it's always shuffling again!